# Parsing big numbers in JSON to strings

Tags: javascript, regex, json, windows

I'm trying to tackle the issue with JSON.parse() rounding big numbers. I know why this is happening but am looking for away around it.

I was thinking a regex which could parse the JSON text and turn all the big ints into strings.

I'm using JavaScript in a Windows 8 app and its got to be dealt with client side.

Got me stumped so far.

The main issue is I have to do this after I receive the response from an XMLHTTPRequest and cant change the original format of the JSON

e.g

```
{ "data" : {
    "username":"Brad", "userID":941022167561310208, "location":"London"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you change the json? add quotes around any number that is sufficiently large?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of JSON that you're using? And how many digits should it be rounded to (or no rounding at all)?

Comment: I know this is ideal but not possible unfortunatly

Comment: It's not possible to include an example of your JSON?

Comment: Sorry, no in response to the first comment. Attached sample now.

Comment: I've updated answer for your case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**

This is an old answer, and the question is even older. You shouldn't ***ever*** be parsing JSON with regular expressions - it's too brittle of a solution, and is liable to break at random. The right way to do this is to parse the entire JSON string, then use code to convert string values to numbers, e.g. `parseInt(jsonData.data.userID)`.

An even better way to do it is to fix it on your back-end so your client doesn't have to do this.

---

Here's the regex to wrap all integers with quotes. If you wanted to do this only for long strings, change `+` to `{9,}` (or any int).

```
var json = ('{"data":{"username":"Brad","userID":941022167561310208,"location":"London","test":"3908349804","test2":"This already exists in 034093049034 quotes"},"list":[3409823408,3409823408,"A list 234908234"]}');
json = json.replace(/([\[:])?(\d+)([,\}\]])/g, "$1\"$2\"$3");
json = JSON.parse(json);
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/6YMYT/

**Edit** Updated to accommodate lists as well.

Here's the regex in action: http://regex101.com/r/qJ3mD2

Comment: Perfect, is there any way you could do this which wouldn't effect numbers already wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Updated again, now it handles lists

Comment: Solved my problem 99%, I was also working with decimals, so I had to just add to the digit selector part of the regex. The new one is:`json = json.replace(/([\[:])?([\d\.]+)([,\}\]])/g, "$1\"$2\"$3");`

Comment: Hey @JoshG see edit. While this technically works, it's really brittle, and I can't in good conscience recommend it.

Comment: @brandonscript I saw, I just wanted to ensure that this was the issue we were facing, and then I figured I'd add what I found, while this doesn't come up much we'll most likely be changing the backend to just not pass raw numbers, thanks for following up with the wisdom and maintaining your answers!

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very old question, but this is the solution you can use if you are using npm. Javascript can handle bigInt of value `9007199254740991` [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint) npm package to parse JSON's containing large numbers.

Install your package

```
npm i json-bigint
```

Then use it like this.

```
var JSONbig = require('json-bigint');
let result = JSONbig.parse(<your-json>);
```

Comment: And if you are already using BigNumber.js you can use this npm package json-bignumber: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bignumber

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use it as a `string` then just save it as a string, with `""`:

```
{ "data" : {
    "username":"Brad", "userID":"941022167561310208", "location":"London"
    }
}
```

You also have a misstake `username` => `"username"`.

You can also parse it to integer with `parseInt()` later

For updated question: Then you need to surround your number with `""` with regexp:

```
s='{"data":{"username":"Brad","userID":9410221675613105435234324235235235235235523208,"location":"London"}}';
s = s.replace(new RegExp('"userID":([0-9]+),',"g"),'"userID":"$1",')
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/E4txx/