# Getting wrong parsing with JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json

I have used the following text as input to JSON.parse()

```js
let inputTxt = `{"result":[{"aliasName":null,"name":"SRDD","sort":0,"id":319488404634063872,"parentId":319472086895578112,"level":2},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Noodles","sort":11,"id":350368638463726592,"parentId":350368638434366464,"level":2},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Sushi","sort":21,"id":350368638463726593,"parentId":350368638434366464,"level":2},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Drink","sort":31,"id":350368638463726594,"parentId":350368638434366464,"level":2},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Set","sort":41,"id":350368739890458624,"parentId":350368638434366464,"level":2},{"aliasName":"默认","name":"默认","sort":1,"id":319472086895578112,"parentId":null,"level":1},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Tendongo","sort":0,"id":350368638434366464,"parentId":null,"level":1}],"code":0,"message":"success[OK]","messageUuid":"437fcce5209d4d17b558403d4a8b859c","apiMessage":null}`

console.log(JSON.parse(inputTxt))
```

Here you can see the id for the category is different in the output.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support numbers that huge; you need to use Strings instead.

Comment: there is no category.  What id are you referring to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17320771/8681416

Comment: @acbay It does not give the answer, It just says, what is the issue, But not how to solve it

Comment: It says don't use them as numbers or use external libraries to handle that. Doesn't it give any idea? Use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20408845/8681416 @xdeepakv

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with a big number. When you parse JSON. It is trying to hold a large number.

**Max value can be seen as :**

`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER  //  (253 - 1) =>  9007199254740991`

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

```js
const str = "319488404634063872"
console.log(Number(str)) // 319488404634063900

// OR
const num  = 319488404634063872

console.log(num) // 319488404634063900
```

You can use replace function as workaround, before parsing `convert it to string`.

```js
let inputTxt = `{"result":[{"aliasName":null,"name":"SRDD","sort":0,"id":319488404634063872,"parentId":319472086895578112,"level":2},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Noodles","sort":11,"id":350368638463726592,"parentId":350368638434366464,"level":2},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Sushi","sort":21,"id":350368638463726593,"parentId":350368638434366464,"level":2},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Drink","sort":31,"id":350368638463726594,"parentId":350368638434366464,"level":2},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Set","sort":41,"id":350368739890458624,"parentId":350368638434366464,"level":2},{"aliasName":"默认","name":"默认","sort":1,"id":319472086895578112,"parentId":null,"level":1},{"aliasName":null,"name":"Tendongo","sort":0,"id":350368638434366464,"parentId":null,"level":1}],"code":0,"message":"success[OK]","messageUuid":"437fcce5209d4d17b558403d4a8b859c","apiMessage":null}`;

const format = (json) => json.replace(/\"id\":(\d+)/g, `"id":"$1"`)

console.log(JSON.parse(format(inputTxt)))
```

Comment: Thanks man... This was exactly the issue..

Comment: haha! still downvote.. an you pleas accept as an answer.