# How to work with big numbers (int64 / bigInt) in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, bigint, int64

As you can see below, in all the cases the number is shown wrong:

```
  var a = 714205074837649919;
  console.log(a); //>> 7.1420507483764992E17
  console.log(parseInt(a)); //>> 7.1420507483764992E17
  console.log(parseInt(a).toString()); //>> 714205074837649900
  console.log(parseFloat(a).toString()); //>> 714205074837649900
```

Comment: What the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9643626/1595451

Answer (score 4):

The Apps Script global environment includes [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

Use strings, not numbers, to avoid rounding errors when providing a literal for the `BigInt` object.

```js
function testBigInt() {
  const bigNumber = BigInt("714205074837649919");
  console.log(bigNumber.toString()); // 714205074837649919
}
```

Comment: To add to this, `n` notation: `1n` throws a syntax error: `Unexpected token ILLEGAL (line 5075, file "esprima.browser.js-bundle.js")` Someone should post a issue in the issuetracker;

Comment: Do you know why it rounds to 7142050748376499'20'? I need the exact number 7142050748376499'19'

Comment: @BrunoYuzo Conversion between number and bigint causes this. Change number to string: `const bigNumber = BigInt("714205074837649919");`

Comment: @BrunoYuzo yes, the number input can't work because it has the normal Number type limitations.  Using a String bypasses the limitations of the Number type.

Comment: The json value that I'm receiving is not a string, as you can see:
`var JsonValue = JSON.parse('[{"GroupId":714205074837649919,"Type":"OrganisationGroup"}]');
  console.log(JsonValue[0].GroupId); //7.1420507483764992E17`

Comment: @BrunoYuzo since you are receiving it that way, you might need to resort to using a RegExp to fix the JSON before parsing.  See [this relevant stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408537/parsing-big-numbers-in-json-to-strings).