# FortiSandbox returns a value and jQuery changes the value when console.log()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, response, console.log

I am getting a JSON response from FortiSandbox API, where I can see in the network tab that the value returned from the API is 699468936711412***8661***, but when I use it to send it or to `console.log()` the value changes to 699468936711412***8000***.

After getting the response from the server I immediately `console.logged` the value and it changed.

My jQuery code

```
  fetch(apiUrl, requestOptionsJobID)
        .then(responsegetJobStatus => {
            if (!responsegetJobStatus.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return responsegetJobStatus.json();
        })
        .then(getJobIDResult => {
            var ok = getJobIDResult.result.status.message;
            if (ok == 'OK') {
                var getJobJid = getJobIDResult.result.data.jids[0];//here is where the value changes to 6994689367114128000
                console.log(getJobJid);//shows the changed value
            }
            return getJobIDResult;
        }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Eroare get job ID: ', error);
    });
```

The API response with the wanted value of jid from the API

```json
{
    "id": 17,
    "ver": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "url": "/scan/result/get-jobs-of-submission",
        "status": {
            "code": 0,
            "message": "OK"
        },
        "data": {
            "jids": [
                6994689367114128661
            ],
            "total_jids": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `6994689367114128661` it outside the valid integer range, so you get the loss of precision that comes with handling the value as a float. If the API can't be convinced to send this is a string value, then you might need to use a different JSON parser explicitly somehow, https://jsoneditoronline.org/indepth/parse/why-does-json-parse-corrupt-large-numbers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that the number you are receiving is too big to be completely handled by javascript. When a number bigger is received, it looses precision. Without entering into exact details, here's a dumbed down example:

Let's say Javascript can only "remember" 10 digits. It could easily handle numbers like 235 or 1,235,038 but not quite 123,123,456,456 as it has 12 digits. To remain somewhat accurate, javascript would then take only the 10 first digits and memorize how many it discarded: 1,231,234,564 since it got rid of 2 digits (divided the number by 100, 10^2 or e2), it is able to show the number still, but only the 10 biggest digits will be accurate so it would turn out like this: 1,231,234,564e2 = 123,123,456,400

This is exactly what you are experiencing. The Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER value gives you the biggest number Javascript can handle with precision. Above that, it will start loosing precision. In the console.log below, you can see the biggest SAFE INTEGER, then a comparison if your number is bigger than it, and again the number as Javascript is seeing it.

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, 6994689367114128661 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, 6994689367114128661);
```

So now, how do we fix this issue? Your best bet is to convert the JSON number into a string. You would use .text() method instead of JSON and manipulate the text to quote the numbers in it. Then parsing the JSON would handle the ID as a string and not a number, since strings are handled completely differently than numbers, you would keep the same value as you received.

See [Parsing big numbers in JSON to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408537/parsing-big-numbers-in-json-to-strings)

Comment: Thank you! Very nice answer, did not know about the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. Also I tried before with .toString() and .stringify() but the value still loses precision. How can I get the value in the call of the then() method, because that is where it loses precision.

 .then(getJobIDResult  <--- here it loses precision => {
            var ok = getJobIDResult.result.status.message;

Comment: No, read carefully the end of the answer. The precision is lost as soon as it becomes a javascript number. This means, it looses precision when you do .json() that is at that point that the *text* body is transformed into *javascript values*. You should replace .json() to .text() to have the plain text version, and then use the regex in the linked answer to put quotes around the id number, and the JSON.parse() it.

Comment: managed to take the response as a string, like you said. and took it apart to get to the number that I was looking for. Thank you!